# How can I use .NET-style escape sequences in runtime values?

Tags: c#, escaping

This problem comes to me when I was writing delimiter value in a XML config file, normally when you write a string like `"\t"` in XML config, parser class like `XDocument` will automatically convert it to `@"\\t"` so that you are getting a backslash and a `'t'` from the string that is parsed from the config. However, what I want is just a tab character rather than a two-character string.

So the problem turns into: given a string containing an escape sequence like `"\t"`, how do I convert it into a one-character tab?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Since these are compile-time literals, there's obviously no programmatic way of doing this (short of writing a utility that sweeps your code or something.)  Are you looking for a Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: what I am looking for is actually a way of writing a tab char in XML config and read it from my program as a char variable.

Comment: So you want to replace the string any occurrence of the the `\t` sequence in a string with a tab character at runtime? But how is that related to string literals?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I edited the question to better reflect what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
stringValue = stringValue.Replace("\\t", "\t");
```

I wrote the following method to replace a bunch of common escape character sequences.

```
    public static string LiteralValue(this string value)
    {
        return value
            .Replace("\\\\", "\\")
            .Replace("\\a", "\a")
            .Replace("\\b", "\b")
            .Replace("\\f", "\f")
            .Replace("\\n", "\n")
            .Replace("\\r", "\r")
            .Replace("\\t", "\t")
            .Replace("\\v", "\v")
            .Replace("\\0", "\0");
    }
```

Comment: For longer strings, this will take a long time to execute, due to the repeated iteration in every `Replace` call.

Comment: Unfortunately this is broken. Just try `@"\\t"`/`"\\\\t"` which will become `"\t"`

Answer (score 4):

How about just removing the `@` prefix?

Verbatim and normal string literals are ways to write strings in your source code. At runtime there is no difference between them. Then they are just plain strings.

If you want to handle escape sequences at runtime you can do something like the following:

```
string ReplaceEscapeSequences(string s)
{
  Contract.Requires(s != null);
  Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
  {
    if(s[i] == '\\')
    {
      i++;
      if(i == s.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Escape sequence starting at end of string", s);
      switch(s[i])
      {
        case '\\':
          sb.Append('\\');
          break;
        case 't':
          sb.Append('\t');
          break;
        ...
      }
    }
    else sb.Append(s[i]);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the right way to do it. You should consider putting the parameter name in the `ArgumentException`.

Comment: It isn't complete and isn't so easy because you have others escape sequences using literals like hexadecimal codes for especial characters. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Comment: @Luciano That's what the `...` signify. It's just a sketch of how to write such an algorithm.

Comment: I undertood that. I only tried to remember that parsing expressions like \u0000 or \x00 isn't just completing "...". Sorry, my comment was very bad. Consider my appologizes and it rewritten with this new comment.